# How to get records count based on 3 keys in mongodb using mongoose?

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I have a model named `referralLink` like this

```
new Schema({
  referral_link: String,
  referral_code : String,
  isLink : Number,
  offer_name: String,
  offer_desc: String,
  user_email: String,
  companyId: { type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : 'companies'},
  addedByAdmin: { type: Boolean, default: true },
  number_of_clicks: Number,
  referral_country: String,
  link_status: String,
  categoryId : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'categories' },
  number_of_clicks : { type: Number, default: 0 },
  createdAt: String,
  updatedAt: String,
  userId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'users' } 
})
```

Now i want count of **Approved**, **Rejected**, **Pending** referrals in single `mongoose` query. I want results like this

```
{
  approved : 2,
  pending : 1,
  rejected : 3
}
```

How can i do this in mongoose?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the approved, pending and rejected values are in the link_status field, then something like this should work:

```
let linkStatusSummary = referralLink.find({}, 'link_status', (err, results) => {
  let counts = {};

  // create an object that contains the possible values of link_status and the number of times each occurs
  for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    let status = results[i].link_status;
    counts[status] = counts[status] ? counts[status] + 1 : 1;  // if the category is already in the object, add 1 to the count, else create a new element with count 1
  }
  return counts
})
```